# How to use parse special characters literally in Apache rewrite rule?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an Apache rewrite rule and I need to parse the ? character from the middle part (`^page.php?...`) literally - not take it as a special character. But I want other special characters to work normally.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a query string that way. You need to use query string in a condition to check if it is there. Then use the captured backreference in the rule. Let me know how it works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^viewstory=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^news\.php$ index.php?page=news&viewStory=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: no, you don't . It works fine for me. Try and clear your cache and try it.